# Ubuntu 12.04 and mono runtime issue

Tags: mono

I am running a .net4 app from my usb disc with mono and runs fine.

I copy the complete app folder to the harddrive (desktop) and start my app with mono and get an error the some isnot found...

I do not see the problem since it runs fine from my usb drive. And i am sure all files are copied , all in one directory)

The full text of the error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: WinForms_SeeInnerException ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnTextChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Text (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain:InitializeComponent ()
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[frmMain] (Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain Instance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_frmMain () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: WinForms_SeeInnerException ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnTextChanged (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Text (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain:InitializeComponent ()
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[frmMain] (Redesigned_Integration_Platform.frmMain Instance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_frmMain () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Redesigned_Integration_Platform.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the mysql-connector-net package:

Development package (required to build / use monodevelop)

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-cil-dev
```

Runtime package (required to run it) the dev package will pull this in automatically

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql6.4-cil
```